# A3 latex page numbering

Tags: numbering, margins

I am writing my end of studies project report on latex (overleaf).
I had to use A3 size pages to insert large size charts and tables but had two issues:

1 / The numbering of the A3 page is no longer displayed (knowing that I use the "plain" style) because I had to change the page margins (to display the graphic centered in the middle).
How could I display it at the bottom center?

2 / The numbering of the A4 page which directly follows the A3 page has moved to the middle of the page
What to do, please?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[paper=A4,pagesize]{typearea}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\begin{document}

\afterpage{
\clearpage
\pagestyle{plain}
\KOMAoptions{paper=a3,paper=landscape}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-17.0cm}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-5.0cm}
\recalctypearea
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3.5\textwidth]{GanttT.PNG}

\caption {Diagramme de Gantt}
\label{fig:vo-business-schema}

\end{figure}

\clearpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=A4,pagesize}
\recalctypearea
}

\newpage
\pagestyle{plain}
\section*{Conclusion}


\end{document}
```

[image][image]

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103057/modify-single-page-size-and-insert-image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When including graphics, in the future please use `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` as the package option and use `\includegraphics["options"]{demo}` in the main body, as your example cannot compile due to us not having access to your `GanttT.PNG`.

I have changed your code quite a lot but it does as you require (page number centred on A3 page, revert back to A4 page normally):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[usegeometry]{typearea}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}

% Assumed a geometry, delete both \newgeometry commands to use the default geometry of your document
\newgeometry{inner=2.5cm,outer=2.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm}

\newcommand\paperAThreeLandscape{%
    \cleardoublepage%
    \KOMAoptions{paper=A3,paper=landscape,DIV=last}%
    \newgeometry{margin=1in}%
    }

\newcommand\afterPaperChange{%
    \clearpage%
    \KOMAoptions{paper=A4,paper=portrait,pagesize}%
    \recalctypearea%
    \newgeometry{inner=2.5cm,outer=2.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm} % Change geometry to what it was set to before
    }

\begin{document}

\section*{Before gantt}

\clearpage
\pagestyle{plain}

\paperAThreeLandscape
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=15cm]{demo}
\caption {Diagramme de Gantt}
\label{fig:vo-business-schema}

\end{figure}

\afterPaperChange

\newpage
\pagestyle{plain}
\section*{Conclusion}

\end{document}
```

This produces this on the A3 page (note the black rectangle is the `demo` graphic):

[image: A3]

And this on the A4 page:

[image: A4]

I cannot remember where I got the code (or parts of it anyway) for changing paper size midway through a document but I think it was [from Martin Scharrer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21431/245306). Change the height option on include graphics to suit your requirements, I selected 15cm just because. Change the margin of the A3 page to what you require too, 1in was selected as that is what I use in my files. I removed the afterpage package, if this is unacceptable then I do not how to do what you require within the confines of that package but hopefully someone else can! Hope this helps.